# Customizing JOptionPane in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane, jdialog

I'm developing a GUI, where I need some pop-up windows with a customized design, for example, the client can add a product to an order by filling a form, and this form will be in a pop-up window with a custom style. Another example is something like this

[After registration: (I can't post images yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2Kg1.png)

My question is, how can I achieve this? I tried to create a JOptionPane and JDialog with a custom class that extends JPanel, but the borders are grey, and the ok button it's still there... Also I would like to remove the top default border with the close button and customize it too, but I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: [Other similar questions on this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+custom+modal+dialog) -- as well as a useful search strategy.

Comment: Or to narrow the 15,500 hits in the search suggested by @HovercraftFullOfEels to just 185, search on [Stack Overflow in tags Java, Swing & JOptionPane for 'custom'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+%5BJOptionPane%5D+custom). [thought I'd try my luck using words & tags in the op's own question]